# Prove or disprove: if $f$ is one-to-one and $g \circ f=h \circ f$ then $g=h$

Tags: functions

I tried using a counterexample but couldn't find one. I also tried proving it by saying that $f(x)=f(y)$ since its one-to-one. Then I set up $g(f(x))=h(f(x))$ but didn't know what else I could do with that. Would I have to prove that $g$ and $h$ is one-to-one?

Comment: Hint: If $f$ is not onto, consider the values of $g$ and $h$ on $x \notin \operatorname{im}(f)$.

Comment: A simple counterexample: $f(x)=2,g(x)=1,h(x)=\frac{x}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

Consider $f:[0,\pi]\to\mathbb{R}$ and  $f(x)=x$, which is injective. Then consider $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and $h:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined as 
$$g(x)=\cos (x)$$
and 
$$h(x)=\left\{
  \begin{array}{ll}
    \cos x, & \hbox{for $x\in[0,\pi]$;} \\
    0, & \hbox{for $x\not\in[0,\pi]$.}
  \end{array}
\right.$$
Clearly, $g(x)\neq h(x)$. But $g(f(x))=h(f(x))=\cos x$ for all $x\in[0,\pi]$.